# Scene children not showing if not added on init

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to show buttons if an object is clicked in SceneKit scene, they are visible as children of scene, but they aren't rendered on screen.

```
init(size: CGSize, gameController: GameController) {
        super.init(size: size)

        self.gameController = gameController
        self.scaleMode = .aspectFit

        // Label is shown in scene
        testLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "test")
        testLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        testLabel.fontSize = 50.0
        testLabel.fontColor = UIColor.red
        addChild(testLabel)

        // Label is not shown in scene
        let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in 
            var label = SKLabelNode(text: "test 2")
            label.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
            label.fontSize = 50.0
            label.fontColor = UIColor.red
            addChild(label)
        }      
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the exact issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making an unscheduled Timer and then just throwing it away.  You likely meant something like Timer.scheduledTimer(...)

In any case, for SpriteKit it's probably better to work within the SKAction framework, otherwise you'll eventually run into issues where, e.g., you've paused your game and your timers are still running because they're not coordinating with SpriteKit.

Look at the SKAction initializers, in particular sequence(), wait(forDuration:), run()

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/action_initializers

Comment: I have a game HUD (SceneKit overlay). I want to "spawn" a node on button click on HUD but when I add a node to scene it shows it in children but it doesn't render it. This timer was a demonstration.